# If $ \int_0^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0$ for all $n$ then prove that $f\equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

> If $f:[0,\pi]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $f(0)=0$ such that $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0$ for all $n=0,1,2,\cdots$ then prove that $f\equiv 0$ in $[0,\pi]$.

I want to apply Weierstrass approximation theorem. As $f$ is continuous so there exists a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n(x)\}$ such that $p_n(x)\to f$ uniformly. If I expand $\cos nx=1+\frac{n^2x^2}{2!}+\cdots$ then $$\int_0^{\pi}f(x)\,dx+\frac{n^2}{2!}\int_0^{\pi}x^2f(x)\,dx+\cdots=0.$$which implies  $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi}x^{2n}f(x)\,dx=0$ for each $n=0,1,2,\cdots$. **Is this step correct ?** If yes then I can deduce from it that $f\equiv 0$. If I am Not correct then solve it please.

Comment: What is the Fourier series for $f$ on $[0,\pi]$?

Comment: In your approach, the integrals $\int_0^{\pi} f(x)x^{2n}\,dx$ need not be zero since $f$ is not restricted to be non-negative.

Comment: $\int_0^{\pi}\cos nxf(x)\,dx=0$ should be retyped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend $f$ to $g$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, s.t. $g(x)=f(-x)$ if $x<0$.
Then $\hat{g}(n)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)cos(nx)dx=0$ for all $n$. By Parseval's identity, $\int |g|^2=0$ which implies $f=0$.

Comment: Seems to me you would want to extend $f$ to be even.

Comment: Yes. You are right .Otherwise, I cant get rid of the sine term.

Comment: @Ben)) Why we need to use Persavals identity ? As we extend $f$ to $\hat f$ and we find that $\hat f=0$  then we can conclude $f \equiv 0$. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 10):

Extend $f$ to be even on $[-\pi,\pi].$ We then have

$$\hat f (n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}\,dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi f(x)\cos (nx)\,dx = 0$$

for all $n\in \mathbb {Z}.$  Thus $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi|f|^2 = \sum |\hat f (n)|^2 = 0.$$

This implies $f\equiv 0.$ I did not use the condition $f(0)=0,$ which makes me think the problem should have been stated assuming $\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin (nx)\, dx =0, n=1,2,\dots.$

Comment: You need zeroth fourier coefficient vanishes and thats where u used f vanishes at zero.

Comment: The $f(0)=0$ assumption is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old post, but I think that the assumption $f(0) = 0$ **is** necessary. I didn't notice it when I read the post initially, and I couldn't understand why no one had pointed out that $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$ satisfies
$$\int_0^\pi f(x) \cos(nx) dx = \int_0^\pi \cos(nx) dx = \frac{1}{n}[\sin(nx)]_{x=0}^{x=\pi} = 0-0=0.$$
But $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$ certainly doesn't satisfy $f(0) = 0$!

Comment: Your displayed equation fails when $n=0.$

Comment: @jhw)) Why we need to use Persavals identity ? As we extend $f$ to $\hat f$ and we find that $\hat f=0$  then we can conclude $f \equiv 0$. Isn't it ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 What argument would you use to conclude that $f = 0$? It's not true without the assumption that $f$ is continuous (you can then only conclude that $f=0$ almost everywhere), so you need to use that somehow. The Parseval argument makes this crystal clear.

Comment: @ Bungo) It is given is question that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Parseval is the way you show $\hat f (n) = 0, n \in Z \implies f \equiv 0.$ If you already know that result, then of course you don't need to repeat it.

Comment: $$\hat f (n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}\,dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi f(x)\cos (nx)\,dx = 0$$   How this happens????????????Can u plzz explain to me?@zhw.

Comment: A discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14150/2017/5/28) related to the last sani's comment.

Answer (score 2):

(Complete revamp of my previous answer.)

Extend $f$ by $f(x) = f(-x)$ for $x \in [-\pi,0)$, then $f$ is $2\pi$ periodic
and so for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a trigonometric polynomial $q$ such that $\|f-q\|_\infty = \sup_{|x|\le \pi} |f(x)-q(x)| < \epsilon$.
(Recall that a trigonometric polynomial is of the form
$q(t) = a_0+\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k \cos(kt) + b_k \sin (kt))$). (See, for example,
Rudin's "Real & Complex Analysis", Theorem 4.25.)

Let $\tilde{q}(t) = {1 \over 2} (q(t)+q(-t))$ and note that
$\|f-\tilde{q}\|_\infty \le {1 \over 2} (\|f-q\|+ \|f-q\|) < \epsilon$ (where 
we used evenness of $f$ for the last part). Hence we may assume that $q$ is
even to begin with, in particular, $q$ has the form
$q(t) = a_0+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \cos(kt) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \cos(kt)$.

Note that, by assumption, $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) q(x) dx = 0$.

Then $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x) dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) (f(x)-q(x)+ q(x)) dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) (f(x)-q(x)) dx$, hence
$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x) dx \le \|f\|_\infty 2 \pi \epsilon$. Since
$\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we see that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x) dx = 0$. Since
$f$ is continuous, and $f^2(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ we see that
$f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: What theorem did you use to have your convergence of $s_n$?

Comment: @user281591: Good question; I used the Riesz Fischer theorem and suspect there might be some circularity in my argument. Let me think about this for a while.

Comment: @user281591: I changed my answer. My original answer was OK, but to justify the $L^2$ convergence of the $s_n$ I needed to use density of the trigonometric polynomials in the continuous functions on the circle using the $\sup$ norm, so it was easier to prove it, using the density result, in a slightly different way.

Comment: thanks for clarifying your answer, I like this proof. +1